# Is there a site for documentation recommendations? And if not, why not?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've several times had issues where I needed a pointer to a good tutorial, or set of references for a programming language or library. This seems to fall into the cracks between Stack Overflow and Software Recommendations.

Is there another site I should be asking these questions on? Or do I need to go onto Area 51 and propose it? (I would feel bad about that, because I actually don't know any of the answers, I just have questions I want to put somewhere!)

Comment: Google is generally the best place to go to find tutorials/documentation/references for a topic.

Comment: Unfortunately my google kung-fu is weak...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Exchange position is stated in [On proposals soliciting reviews, recommendations, comparisons, etc](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc):

> proposals have pushed out even further into website recommendations, book recommendations, travel recommendations, idea exchanges, essay reviews, textbook errata, job scams registries, software comparisons, suggest-a-song —
>
> I don't have any regrets with the sites we tried, but hardware and software search is about as far as we can take this format; we don't wish to keep expanding this model any further.

So, don't bother proposing on Area 51. There is probably a programming forum or two outside of Stack Exchange network; they may be okay with documentation recommendations.